# i have error in my css html code how fix

Tags: css, html

i need to fix Last Reviews From Customers loop list in vue.js, and i have css error :

[example image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFqW8.png)

live url : https://jobdone.net/freelancer/daredevil.html

where im wrong ?

Comment: first you should read how to ask question on stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add a code sample consisting of the code having the error in question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

because you have floats on items inside .comments--item div this one won't hold the height so what I would suggest is clear the floats, try the one below

```
.comments--item:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why there are some people whom just downvoting even if the answer is correct !!